# Why does my struct stat have a st_mtim instead of st_mtime field?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

For my computer science class, we are implementing the "ls" functionality in a C program and required to use the st_mtime field. When I use struct stat, however, it only has a st_mtim field and not the st_mtime field I need. This matches what I see in the header file in /usr/include/sys/stat.h. How can I get the struct definition which has the field I need?

Comment: what version/distro of Linux and C++ doe you have?

Comment: Are they doing different things according to the docs? or is it a typo?

Answer (score 7):

I took a look at this on my system (Debian).

For some reason, `st_mtime` is defined as a macro; the definition is `st_mtim`.

Ignore the contents of the headers (they're meant more for the compiler than for human readers), and just follow the documentation. `man 2 stat` will tell you which headers you need to include, and at least on my system it shows a sample program.

---

The gory details (which you don't need to know to use it correctly):

In `/usr/include/bits/stat.h`, the type `struct stat` is defined with the following members (among others):

```
struct timespec st_atim;        /* Time of last access.  */
struct timespec st_mtim;        /* Time of last modification.  */
struct timespec st_ctim;        /* Time of last status change.  */
```

A `struct timespec` is a structure that contains, among other things, a member of type `time_t` called `tv_sec`. (Other member allows for higher resolution timestamps.)

This is followed by the following preprocessor directives:

```
# define st_atime st_atim.tv_sec
# define st_mtime st_mtim.tv_sec
# define st_ctime st_ctim.tv_sec
```

So you can just refer to `foo.st_mtime` in your own code, and it will expand to `foo.st_mtim.tv_sec`, which is the `time_t` object that you need.

**UPDATE** :

The declarations of `st_atim` et al are preceded (on my current Ubuntu 18.04 system) by this comment:

```
/* Nanosecond resolution timestamps are stored in a format
   equivalent to 'struct timespec'.  This is the type used
   whenever possible but the Unix namespace rules do not allow the
   identifier 'timespec' to appear in the <sys/stat.h> header.
   Therefore we have to handle the use of this header in strictly
   standard-compliant sources special.  */
```

Answer (score 0):

On my Distro (Fedora) the `st_time` is defined as a macro, as below as the modification time include the nanoseconds of the modification time using the `struct timespec`

```
$ grep -R st_mtim  /usr/include
....
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:    struct timespec st_mtim /* Time of last modification.  */
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:# define st_mtime st_mtim.tv_sec
....
```

The macro is done so as to be backward compatible with the st_time field which is documented in `man fstat` -- so just use it as documented, or use the full timer resolution if you want to do better than seconds....